# Idioms similar to "put points over i"

Tags: idiom-requests

There is one good common idiom in Russian language:

> Let's put points over i.

It means: let's finalize our decisions, make everything super clear (sometimes: come up with some agreements). [(Idiom's wiki page.)](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4_%C2%ABi%C2%BB)

So, question: Is there an analog for this idiom in English?

Comment: Are you sure that's what it means in Russian? Because the same phrase in English has a completely different meaning (as explained in the  answer given by Jacinto).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is basically the same [(The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary via Dictionary.com):](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dot-the-i-s-and-cross-the-t-s)

> **dot the i's and cross the t's**
>   Be meticulous and precise, fill in all the particulars, as in *Laura had dotted all the i's and crossed the t's, so she wondered what she'd done wrong*. This expression presumably began as an admonition to schoolchildren to write carefully and is sometimes shortened. William Makepeace Thackeray had it in a magazine article ( *Scribner's Magazine*, 1849): “I have . . . dotted the i's.” [Mid-1800s ]

Comment: Commonly used as _Dot the i's_ only

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for that; *The American Heritage* says "sometimes shortened," but I think I've only encountered the full version.

Comment: "Let's wrap this up" is another expression; "that's a wrap" is a Hollywood term now more general indicating completion.